# Changing text color after input is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a change background color button using only css and the problem I'm facing is the text stays the same color after the background color changed.

The label's ID is "switch" for changing the background.
The text's ID is "par".

Here is what I've tried:

```js
document.getElementById("switch").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("par").style.color = 'red';
}
```

I put an alert message first to test it was working, and when I clicked on the input button the message box alert came up. Yet when I replace the alert box with the code from above, my text stays the same color.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Please include example HTML in a snippet demo using the editor. See [ask].

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint using the browsers source debugger and see if you really get the "par" element.  You can also try fiddling whit the command in the console to se where it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("switch").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
 document.getElementById("par").style.color = 'red';
});
```

```css
#switch{
height : 100px;
width : 100px;
background-color : orange;
opacity;0.25;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div id="switch">
      <p id="par">foo bar </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.getElementById("switch").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
 document.getElementById("par").style.color = 'red';
});
```